# NestJS + Passport-steam: Failed to discover OP endpoint URL

Tags: nestjs, passport.js

I am using passport-team as my Strategy in my NestJS application. Everything was working fine yesterday but today I'm getting this error:

`InternalOpenIDError: Failed to discover OP endpoint URL`
This error is thrown eventually from this line in `node_modules\.pnpm\openid@2.0.11\node_modules\openid\openid.js:757:14`:
 `return callback({ message: 'No providers found for the given identifier' }, null);`

I debugged the variables in `passport-openid` and it looks like `authenticate` is called two times. The first time there is no error, I have providerUrl and correct identifier (if I navigate to the providerUrl it is the correct url I should be redirected to). But the second the error is `{ message: 'No providers found for the given identifier' }` and the providerUrl is null.

How come I am not redirected on the first call? This is my auth controller:

```
@Controller('auth')
export class AuthController {
    constructor(private readonly authService: AuthService) {}

    @Get('steam')
    @UseGuards(SteamGuard)
    steamLogin() {}
}
```